# Meteor observeChanges removed callback won't execute server methods

Tags: meteor

I am observing changes on the Results collection on the client and calling methods on the server for the added and removed callbacks. (The following is only on the client and 'foo' is on the server.)

```
Results.find().observeChanges({
    added: function (id, doc) {
      console.log('added on client')
      Meteor.call('foo')
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      console.log('removed on client')
      Meteor.call('foo')
    }
})
```

Here is the server code.

```
Meteor.methods({
    foo: function() {
        console.log('server code run')
    }
})
```

If I insert a document on the client I get 'added on client' on the client and 'server code run' on the server. If I remove a document on the client, I get 'removed on the client' on the client, but nothing on the server at all.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Does the code run on the server (e.g if you put it into a `Tracker.autorun` block)?
- Are there any errors on the server console?
- Is there any error on the browser console?

If other code within the `removed` callback gets executed, the server method call will be executed too. There are no restrictions for these callbacks. I don't think your problem is with the code you've pasted. Maybe add the server method code as well.

Comment: Yes, the code snippet above does run on the server, and I actually moved it  to the client only because I am interested specifically in minimongo collection changes only on the client. There are no errors on the server or browser console. I've updated the question to add a little more detail.